# Finding the coefficient of friction when a body is being pulled at an angle

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, classical-mechanics, applications

I'm answering the following question, but am getting a different answer to the one given in the answers pages:

A body of mass 100g rests on a rough horizontal surface and has a light string, inclined at 20° above the horizontal, attached to it.  When the tension in the string is 5 x $10^{-1}$ N, the body is found to be in limiting equilibrium.  Find the coefficient of friction between the body and the surface.

I drew a diagram and resolved vertically to get R = 0.1g - 0.2sin(20)

Since it's in limiting equilibrium, the friction force F = $F_{max}$ = $\mu$R = $\mu$(0.1g - 0.2sin(20))

Then resolving horizontally gives F = 0.2cos(20), i.e. $\mu$(0.1g - 0.2sin(20)) = 0.2cos20, so $\mu$ = $\frac{0.2cos20}{0.1g - 0.2sin(20)}$ = 0.206

However, the answers in the back say that $\mu$ = 0.58

Where am I going wrong?!  I can't work it out.

Many TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small typo caused the error. You should put the string tension to be $0.5$ instead of $0.2$, and you'll get the correct answer.

Comment: Ah, amazing - what a stupid mistake.  Thanks so much!